# Image element becoming null on src change? Slideshow

Tags: javascript, html

Working on building a library, trying to put in a fading image slider, it shows the first image, but then when it tries to change I get TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null. Any help would be great!

```
 export let styl = (function() {
  let slideIndex = 0;
  return {

    simpleSlideShow: function() {
      //automatic Slider
      let i;
      let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      console.log("Image change");
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      slideIndex++;
      if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1;
      }
      slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    },
    slideShowImageSetup: function(timeDelay, id, images) {
      //Building HTML with given array of images
      let i;
      for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        let elem = document.createElement("img");
        elem.setAttribute("alt", "image");
        elem.setAttribute("src", images[i]);
        elem.setAttribute("class", "mySlides");
        document.querySelector(id).appendChild(elem);
      }
      setTimeout(styl.simpleSlideShow, 1);
      setInterval(styl.simpleSlideShow, timeDelay);
      return 1;
    },
    fadingSlideShow: function(id, images) {
      document.querySelector(id).className += "fadeOut";
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.querySelector(id).src = images[slideIndex];
        document.querySelector(id).className = "";
        slideIndex++;
        if (slideIndex == images.length) {
          slideIndex = 0;
        }
        setTimeout(styl.fadingSlideShow(id, images), 3000);
      }, 1000);
    },
  };
})();
```

Where I'm calling the function

```
let images = [
  "https://cdn141.picsart.com/297231911148201.jpg?c256x256",
  "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSQIfOEjoaYJNDHGmdgRa8EQp50VCicpK0R_0QpZLftE2zzgJky"
];

styl.fadingSlideShow("#slider", images);
```

```
<img id="slider"></img>
```

css that makes the fade effect

```
#slider {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 3s;
}

#slider.fadeOut {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: add full code slideIndex is not define...

Comment: Might not be relevant to the question, but rather than doing `element.className += "class"` you can use `element.classList.add/remove/toggle('className')`, which is a lot cleaner.

Comment: update the question  with the whole javascript object your using

Comment: @Doc-Han Gotcha

Comment: Code works fine for me. both images are displayed. [check here](https://repl.it/repls/BelovedAggravatingProspect) Just that I don't see any fade

Comment: @Doc-Han Lucky... heh, in my inspector it shows my src changing images, no errors, but it's not displaying the images on the screen anymore, as if it's invisible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second setTimeout is not sending in the id or images to styl.fadingSlideShow.

```
setTimeout(function(){styl.fadingSlideShow(id, images)}, 3000);
```

Also, put the second setTimeout inside the first one.

Comment: Thanks! but now I'm getting "too much recursion" xD

Comment: Put the second timeout inside the first one.  That's a different issue though, and is proof the solution worked...

Comment: Can't do that, stops the recursion but then the slideIndex++ and that last if statement never get called

Comment: They should also be in the first setTimeout, but at the beginning.

Comment: Now I'm back to the querySelector is null. lol, I updated my code to show more of what's going on

Comment: You are also fading out the first image that was never set, so so might want to fix that delay.

Comment: Your code is still not using a callback function to provide the id.  And now you are calling it several timed without them.  `setTimeout(styl.fadingSlideShow, 3000)`. Remove the second one outside the first setTimeout. And fix the first one.

Comment: BTW once we solved your first issue on SO, you should have created a new issue for the recursion.

Comment: I gotcha, I fixed those changes, getting no errors now but nothing is being displayed, first image was before I added the id and image varibles back into the second setTimeout

Comment: Did you fix all the setTimeouts, and the setInterval too?

Comment: There is no setInterval?

Comment: Also you don't need the both the setInterval and the internal setTimeout.  That is going to cause a chain reaction...

Comment: `setInterval(styl.simpleSlideShow, timeDelay);`

Comment: You're looking at the wrong function haha, it's the fading slide show

Comment: Also I'm looking in my inspector right now, and it shows the src being changed, and no errors, but it's not displaying any of the images. This is very strange to me

Comment: Is opacity set to 0?

Comment: It is, so if you look at it, at the start it adds the .fadeOut class, that class has opacity: 0, but then when it gets removed, the #slider has opacity 1: transition: opacity 3s,

Comment: but once it gets set to .fadeOut, afterwards when it sets it back to an empty string, it's not actually setting it to an empty string. it's not setting it at all